# Trying to see if both UITextFields inside of UITableViewRowCell contain text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that contains custom tableView cells.  This custom UITableViewCell contains two UITextFields.  I have assigned each one of the textFields a tag value, and what I would like to do is determine if both UITextFields contain text.  I would like to do this as the user is entering values inside the UITextFields, such that once a user has entered text in UITextField A, and has entered a character in UITextField B or vice versa (i.e. user has entered text in UITextField B, and entered a single character in UITextField B), an event or action is triggered.  I realize that I need to use the UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {}
```

however, my problem is that I am not sure how to reference BOTH UITextFields while using this method.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the reference to the active custom UITableViewCell while I am in this method.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I will do:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    UITextField *theOtherTextField = nil;

    // Get a list of sibling views of the textField
    for( UIView *sub in textField.superview.subviews ){
        if( textField!=sub && [sub isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] ){
            theOtherTextField = (UITextField *)sub;
        }
    }

    // Now you have 'textField' and 'theOtherTextField' ready to use
}
```

BTW, this is how you get a reference to the cell, but it is depending on how deep you have your textfields in the `UITableViewCell`'s view hierarchy:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview;
```

And you probably set your `UITableView` as the `UITextFieldDelegate`. If you would like to change so that the `UITableViewCell` as the `UITextFieldDelegate`, you may be able to avoid most of the trouble above.

Answer (score 1):

You walk up the superviews of the UITextField until you find a UITableViewCell. You then ask the tableview for the index of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

In custom cell, you have two property textField1 and textField2 reference to two text field in your cell. When delegate textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange: invoked, you will check use two above property:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (self.textField1.text.length > 0 && self.textField2.length > 0) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

You can also detect that property corresponse with which text field:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == self.textField1) {
        // text field 1's text changed
    }
    else if (textField == self.textField2) {
        // and this is text field 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have IB outlets for these textFields because they are contained inside the custom UITableViewCell class, this is why I can't use this approach.

Comment: @syedfa You put the IBOutlets *in* the custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: If you use IB, you can drag IB Outlet from IB to your code to custom UITableViewCell class. If you don't use IB, declare text field properties and alloc it

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`! I see that so often and it isn't what that method is there for. That method is for stopping invalid input, for example entering letters in a number field.

Instead subclass `UITableViewCell` and make your custom cell. Give it a couple of IBActions and have its `UITextFields` connect to those actions with the `EditingChanged` event. Keep track of what values are in them from there. You could also give the class a couple IBOutlets if you want to peek at the values.

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom Cell, since you have already tagged them, you can access the TextField with help of those tags.
Make two private instance of textFields, then inside initWithStyle, assign them with your textFields Tag.

```
_textField1 = [self viewWithTag:tag1];
_textField2 = [self viewWithTag:tag2];
_textField1.delegate = self;
_textField2.delegate = self;
```

Now inside textField Delegate method, you can check for the text length of both textFields.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if(_textField1.text.length > 0 && _textField2.text.length > 0){
    // write the action you want to do here
    }
}
```